# deleting specific part of a string in C

Tags: c, string

Hey guys I am trying to delete a specific part of a string...in specific when the user enters a string if the string is part of the old string i delete it...here is an hypothetical input and expected output:
string: "/hello/world/iamsleepy"
to be deleted : "/world"
output: "/hello/iamsleepy"

i tried to do this using  strstr, below is the code i am working with...but it doesn't work...let me know what i am doing wrong...or is there any other way to tackle this?

```
   char* string_delete(char* oldstr, char* str_to_remove){

      char* newstr = malloc(strlen(oldstr) - strlen(str_to_remove)+1);
      char* address = strstr(oldstr, str_to_remove);
       memcpy(newstr, oldstr, address - oldstr);
      memcpy(newstr + address - oldstr, address+strlen(str_to_remove), strlen(newstr)-    strlen(str_to_remove));
       return newstr;

      }
```

Comment: Be more specific. "it doesn't work" doesn't work here.

Comment: [`memmove`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/memmove) should be on your to-read list, paying particular attention to the notes about how it supports overlapped memory regions, where [`memcpy`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/memcpy) does *not*.

Comment: the compiler returns the following error:invalid operands to binary + ( have char* and char*)

Comment: Methinks `newstr + address - oldster` should be `newstr + (address - oldster)`

Answer (score 0):

Try following code:

```
char* string_delete(char* oldstr, char* str_to_remove){
       char* address = strstr(oldstr, str_to_remove);
       if (NULL == address) {
            return NULL;    
      }
      int new_len = strlen(oldstr) - strlen(str_to_remove);
      char* newstr = (char *)malloc(new_len+1);

      memcpy(newstr, oldstr, address - oldstr);
      memcpy(newstr + (address - oldstr), address+strlen(str_to_remove), strstr(oldstr) - strlen(str_to_remove));
      newstr[new_len] = '\0';
      return newstr;
}
```

Your `strlen(newstr)` is not right, should be `strlen(oldstr)`. And you need add '\0' to the end of `newstr`.

Edit: The following function will remove all the string of str_to_remove in oldstr and will return "a" to string_delete("aaaa", "aaa"). But its pitfalls is that every time it will alloc a same size of memory of oldstr to the newstr and then realloc it to the real memory. Maybe it's not very efficient. If you don't care the oldstr anymore after you call this function, you can return the changed oldstr and need not alloc new memory. I hope it helps.

```
char* string_delete(char* oldstr, char* str_to_remove){
    int len_to_remove = strlen(str_to_remove);
    int len_old = strlen(oldstr);

    char *newstr = (char *)malloc(len_old + 1);
    memcpy(newstr, oldstr, len_old + 1);

    char *pos = newstr;
    while ( ( pos = strstr(newstr, str_to_remove) ) != NULL ) {
        int cnt = strlen(pos + len_to_remove);
        memmove(pos, pos + len_to_remove, cnt + 1);
    }
    newstr = (char *)realloc(newstr, strlen(newstr) + 1);
    return newstr;
}
```

By the way, if my English express is not clear or right, please let me know, I am practising English. thx

Comment: If the string to be deleted does not exist has not been taken into account. Or if you want to present multiple times.

Comment: @BLUEPIXY thank you for pointing it out. my code needs to do that too.

Comment: @xuzhezhao thanks the code works...but it fails when they are multiple substrings which match are to be deleted....

Comment: @sl1406 I update my answer, you can try the second function I write. thx

Answer (score 0):

I see the following problems in your code.

1. The cases where the string to be deleted is not found in the source string is not handled correctly.
2. Using `strlen(newstr)` before it is a null terminated string causes undefined behavior.
3. The expression `newstr + address - oldstr` is bad because it is evaluated from the left to the right. `newstr + address` is not a valid expression. You need to use `newstr + (address - oldstr)`.
4. The returned string is not null terminated.

Here's a version of the function that addresses the issues.

```
char* string_delete(char* oldstr, char* str_to_remove){

   size_t len_old = strlen(oldstr);
   size_t len_rem = strlen(str_to_remove);
   char* address = strstr(oldstr, str_to_remove);
   size_t len_new;

   char* newstr = NULL;
   if ( address == NULL )
   {
      newstr = malloc(len_old+1);
      strcpy(newstr, oldstr);
   }
   else
   {
      len_new = len_old-len_rem;
      newstr = malloc(len_new+1);
      memcpy(newstr, oldstr, address - oldstr);
      memcpy(newstr + (address - oldstr),
             address + len_rem,
             len_new - (address - oldstr) + 1);
   }
   return newstr;
}
```

Comment: what if they are multiple instances of the string we want to  delete....i want to delete those too...

Comment: That case is a little bit more complex. For example, how may `"aaa"`s are in `"aaaaa"`? One or three?